# How to StreamReader same stream in two methods?

Tags: c#

I am trying to read from a .json file in two different methods, like so:

```
void mainMethod() 
{
    Stream theFile = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourcesStream("pathToFile");

    Method1(theFile);

    Method2(theFile);

}

void Method1(Stream file)
{
   using (StreamReader fileUsage_1 = new StreamReader(file))
   {
      //do stuff with file
   }
}

void Method2(Stream file)
{
   using (StreamReader fileUsage_2 = new StreamReader(file))
   {
      //do stuff with file
   }
}
```

Running the `mainMethod()` gives the exception: `Stream was not readable.` in `Method2()` I believe the problem is that `Method2()` is trying to read `theFile` when it is still being used in `Method1()`. I thought the `using` blocks closed the file automatically? How can I customize the way I am reading `theFile` in `Method1()` and `Method2()` so they don't "overlap"?

Comment: Your Method1() closed not just the StreamReader but also the "theFile" stream.

Comment: @HansPassant so how do I work around this?

Comment: Just can of course just call GetManifestResourcesStream() again.  Or use the StreamReader constructor with the *leaveOpen* argument.

Comment: @HansPassant that constructor requires two additional parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952(v=vs.110).aspx, neither which I know how/want to implement

Answer (score 2):

Open the StreamReader once and set the position when in each Method. This way the order of calling methods is not fixed. When you first open the StreamReader the position is set to the beginning by default, so the first call to Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin) is redundant but allows for the order of calling to be interchanged in the future.

```
    void mainMethod() 
    {
        Stream theFile = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourcesStream("pathToFile");
        using (StreamReader fileUsage = new StreamReader(theFile))
        {
            Method1(fileUsage);
            Method2(fileUsage);
        }
    }

    private static void Method1(StreamReader fileUsage)
    {
        if (fileUsage != null && fileUsage.BaseStream.CanSeek && fileUsage.BaseStream.CanRead)
        {
            fileUsage.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            fileUsage.DiscardBufferedData();
            Console.WriteLine(fileUsage.ReadLine());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` unless the intent is only to read the first line of the stream.

Comment: @Nick I agree. I was using ReadLine as an example of reading some of the data since I'm not sure of the actual intended use.

Answer (score 1):

Call me crazy...but can't you simply abstract the using statement out of the methods and into the main program? Like so. Edited to include reseting of position if you choose to do so. (Can go to [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.discardbuffereddata.aspx) for more information on discarding buffer data)

```
namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Stream theFile = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("ConsoleApplication12.test.txt");
            using (StreamReader fileUsage_1 = new StreamReader(theFile))
            {
                Method1(fileUsage_1);
                ResetPosition(theFile, fileUsage_1); // If needed
                Method2(fileUsage_1);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Method2(StreamReader fileUsage)
        {
            var test = fileUsage.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Method1(StreamReader fileUsage)
        {
            var test = fileUsage.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void ResetPosition(Stream s, StreamReader sr)
        {
            s.Position = 0;
            sr.DiscardBufferedData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested it out with a a file that is UTF8 encoded with BOM and appears to work fine

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading whole stream is possible if:

1. stream is seekable (`stream.CanSeek == true`)
2. readers don't close stream

You generally have no control over 1, but you can copy whole srteam into seek-able one if needed (i.e. using `Stream.Copy` to `MemoryStream`).

To stop reader from closing stream - use constructor that does not take ownership of stream and as reslut will not close stream after using. I.e. [StreamReader(...,bool leaveOpen)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Finally you need to seek stream to position where other reader need to start (often beginning) with something like `Stream.Position = 0;`

Notes

- if you just need to continue reading stream with `Method2` from the point where `Method1` left you don't need to seek, just make sure readers don't close stream.
- alternatively you can explicitly not close readers (removing `using` / `.Close` call), but such code would look wrong and when one "fixes" it by adding `using` it will no longer work correctly.

Comment: Can you please specify where I need to put what code?

Comment: @user3772119 there are reasonable samples in other answers already.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Stream.Position as previously stated.
set it thus:

file.Seek(System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

Also the Using blocks on the StreamReader close the underlying stream when they exit. You can use the File.ReadAllText method to Open, Read and Close(Dispose) of a File all with that single call:

string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

Comment: Where do I set the stream position? In the `using` blocks of both methods, before I do anything with the file?